# NPM EXPRESS MSSQL APP.POST no hace update al recorset pero hace insercion en SQL Server

Tags: sql, nodejs, express, npm

Estoy intentando que app.post agregue una fila a la tabla en SQL Server (eso si logro realizar), y luego que me actualice el website con el nuevo row (eso no logro realizar y es la razon del por que hago esta pregunta en stackoverflow)

Este es mi codigo en nodejs utilizando npm express y mssql:

```
const sql = require('mssql')
var express = require("express");
var app = express();


var config = {

    server: "serverName",
    user: "sa",
    password: "myPassword",
    database: "myDB",
    port: 1433,
    options: {
        encrypt: false
    }
};


        app.post("/",function(req,res,next){

            (async function () {
                    try {
                        let pool = await sql.connect(config)
                        let result1 = await pool.request()              
                            .query(`insert into demoTest values ('6', 'BlingOn')`)                      
                       // console.dir(result1)  
                       pool.close()
                    } catch (err) {
            // ... error checks
                    }
            })()

        next()

        })  


        async function main(){    

                async function fetchData2 () {
                    try {
                        let pool = await sql.connect(config)
                        let result2 = await pool.request()
                            //.input('input_parameter', sql.Int, value)
                            .query(`select * from demoProbando`) 

                        return result2
                        pool.close()
                    } catch (err) {
                        // ... error checks
                    }
                }

                let abc2 = await fetchData2();                  

                app.all("/",function(req,res){

                    res.render("inicio.ejs",{abc2: abc2})
                    console.log(abc2)
                })

        }

        main()





  app.listen(3000)
```

Entonces el website me carga perfectamente bien y corro el comando app.post perfectamente bien (juzgando por el hecho que puedo agregar una fila a la tabla en SQL Server), sin embargo, al hacerle console.log en el app.all no aparece que se actualice el recordset y la pag web reloads sin la nueva data. Por favor ayuda.